# How should I react if I rejected a candidate but still been considered for the role

Tags: interviewing, manager, reinterviewing

I am having around 7 years of experience and definetely the key member of my team.

Recently I interviewed a candidate, and I did not find him suitable for the role and so gave negative feedback to my manager.

Except me, there was one more guy who interviewed him and he gave positive feedback for him. (he has slightly more experience than me, but does it matter?)

Based on that, they have decided to consider the candidate for the role.

Now, how should I react to this. 
I am considering of boycotting all the future interview because its kind of really not acceptable for me. But not sure if this will be good.

Please help me here, how I should react with this? I can not sit idle.

Comment: Have you talked about this to the others? Do you understand their perspective on the candidate. Or have you all just silently reported to your manager?

Comment: I gave feedback directly to the manager.

Comment: I can't be bothered to write an answer, but the implication is clear. Go talk to your colleagues

Comment: If you are not the hiring manager, then yours is an opinion, not a decision, and only one opinion.  It is not uncommon for a candidate to get negative feedback from one team member and still be considered.  Keep in mind that the same may have been true when you interview as well.

Comment: No, boycotting the company because they made a decision you disagree with is not a good idea, although I'm not sure why that even needs saying.

Comment: Strange.. What's wrong in tht question.. Asking for help or suggestions not allowed here? Why so much down voting for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you own the company? If not, **hiring decisions are the company business**, and you should not care about them. If you are really annoyed, consider looking for some new job. Managers make mistakes all the time and are usually incompetent (read about [Peter's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter's_Principle)...). BTW, you probably won't manage better than your current manager (because the brain of the human species is not well suited for management).

> I am considering of boycotting all the future interview

That is a very excessive reaction. However, for some interviews (not all of them) you might tell that you don't have time to follow them, because you have more urgent tasks.

At last, there might be issues you are not aware of. Perhaps the job market is difficult for hiring companies, and the company prefer to hire someone now instead of looking for some better candidate during several months. Or perhaps they don't have the budget (or time) to hire someone better. Perhaps hiring that person is important to the company (or to the manager) for reasons you don't know (even if the candidate is incompetent).

And that candidate might be incompetent, but willing to learn and pleasant to work with. Probably the company is expecting you to teach him things.

BTW, the workplace is not a rational or optimal world.

Comment: yes.. right.. I should not care.. but he will be part of my team . I being one of the most experienced person in my team, I want my decision to be respected. Anyway you are right, May be I should react with coldness than taking any aggressive decision.

Comment: You don't choose with whom you have to work. That is true everywhere (except if you start your own company). And as a software developer, you are not the best qualified for hiring decisions. At last, the workplace is not a rational or optimal world. And the candidate might be incompetent, but still willing to learn and pleasant to work with. Maybe they expect you to teach him?

Answer (score 4):

In general, when asked for advice on a management decision, you should give your best advice and explain the reasons for it. Sometimes the manager will go with your recommendation. Especially when the manager is getting different recommendations from different experts, other times they will follow another course of action.

Regardless, you owe your employer your best effort to making management decisions work.

In the hiring context, that means giving your honest opinion on the job candidate. Even if you think they are not suitable, and that another candidate would be a better choice, if management does decide to hire them you should do everything you can to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, how should I react to this.

You do not.

You gave your feedback but you do not know what criteria the hiring manager had in mind. May be they were looking for at least 1 positive feedback and does not matter who does that come from. May be HR gave good feedback as well. May be manager thought the candidate is overall good but could learn and pick up skills "on-the-job" which you thought they do not have.  There are just so many possibilities.

If your job description includes providing feedback based on technical interview and not be involved in final hiring decision, then this is exactly what you need to do.

BTW, few years back I was myself hired even though a senior colleague of me gave negative feedback about me after my interview with him. My manager went by her gut feelings and I did very well in that role. My manager told me my hiring story few years later.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, how should I react to this

Your managers made a decision against your recommendation. Your job is to make the best of the situation. When the new person starts, be helpful to him. As the key member of your team, you are in a position to help him become a productive coworker and a good member of the team. Use that position and your own experience to make the team stronger. It may turn out that your advice was right and they were wrong in hiring him; if so, that will become apparent. Or it may turn out that they other people who were interviewing saw things that weren't apparent in the interview you did, and they were right in hiring him. In either case, you being a gracious and courteous mentor will make your own position stronger within the company.

Of course, you can also choose to show your displeasure to your coworkers, your manager and of course to the new hire. You can try to make them feel bad for disagreeing with you and going against your recommendation. You can be cold and show disdain, or display anger and frustration, or be unpleasant to the new hire, or any combination thereof. That will show your manager that you really shouldn't be in any position where you have influence over other people, and it'll be unlikely that they ever invite you on another interview again. (Except possibly an exit interview.)